# mouseover doesn't work when mouse doesn't move over a dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, jquery-events, mouseenter

I'm trying to fire an event when the mouse touches a dynamic element on the site regardless of whether the mouse is moving or not.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't manage to fire the event **unless the mouse moves** over the dynamic element.

Here's a fiddle where you can easily reproduce it by just **leaving the mouse stationary** in the future position of the dynamic square element:

http://jsfiddle.net/rHZbt/1/

I'm trying to fire the even with the following code:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#demo', function(){
    alert("Entering in demo");
});
```

I know there's a way by tracing the mouse and the element position, but that sounds more like a hack or an alternative and complicate way to do it rather than a good solution for the problem. 
When many objects come in place (10 - 40), that solution sounds like a lot of work for the machine.

The problem takes place in:

- Chrome
- Safari
- IE
- Opera

In Firefox it seems to be working properly.

Comment: I dont follow the question it appears to work fine here

Comment: @Dale are you leaving the mouse stationary?

Comment: Completely agree with @Dale. Your code works

Comment: No.. but how can a hover event happen if the mouse doesnt move.. are you perhaps looking to make this happen without any interaction instead?

Comment: @Satpal, dale, I updated my question with the browsers in which it doesn't work as expected (mainly all except Firefox)

Comment: @Dale, because the element is moving. As in the demo. Or when the element is dynamically added under the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).on('mouseout', '#demo', function(){
    alert("Leaving demo");
    });`

By this you can get alert while leaving the mouse stationary.

Comment: It doesn't work on Chrome, Opera, Safari or IE. Same problem as `mouseenter` when the element is dynamically added into the DOM or when its position changes when the mouse is stationary.